# If a derivative is defined everywhere and $\pm1$ almost everywhere, is it constant?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, bounded-variation

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that the set $A:=\{x\in\mathbb{R};f'(x)\not\in\{1,-1\}\}$ has measure $0$. Does this imply that $f'$ is constant?

Context: I was thinking about a question whose author probably meant "continuously differentiable curves" instead of just "differentiable curves", but I wanted to think about the general case. I don't know anything about functions with discontinuous derivative so I have no idea if the answer will be yes or no.

Edit: As Christian Remling mentions in the comments, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/266399/172802) is another answer which implies that if $f'$ was not constant, then the measure of $A$ would be greater than $0$. Also, as mentioned by Mateusz Kwaśnicki below, [a paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-53/issue-2/A-property-of-derivatives/bams/1183510405.full) was devoted to proving this result.

Comment: The derivative of an everywhere differentiable real-valued function satisfies the intermediate value property (a theorem of Darboux). Hence if $f'$ takes 2 different values, say $f'(a)=y_a$ and $f'(b)=y_b$ with, say, $y_a<y_b$, then $f'([a,b])$ contains the interval $[y_a,y_b]$. I'm pretty sure that prevents $A$ from having 0 Lebesgue measure, except if $f'$ is constant (I may be wrong, though).

Comment: This is answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266377/how-quickly-can-the-derivative-of-an-everywhere-differentiable-function-change-s

Comment: Thanks to both!

Comment: To spell this out more explicitly (it is trivial, but perhaps mildly confusing for a moment): If $f'$ is not constant, let's say $f'(a)=1$, $f'(b)=y\not=1$, apply the linked answer with $y$ taking the role of $-1$.

Comment: You will like [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183510405) :-)